# Applescripting MS Word: cannot save to iCloud location - active document doesn’t understand the “save as” message

Tags: icloud, applescript, ms-office

I have a pretty standard AppleScript that opens a series of Word documents and converts them to PDF. The pertinent part of the script can be boiled down to:

```
property desktopPath : (path to desktop) as alias
property iCloudPath : "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~CloudDocs:Letters:"

tell application id "com.microsoft.Word"
    activate
    
    set theFilename to "test.pdf"
    
    tell active document
        save as it file name iCloudPath & theFilename file format format PDF
        --save as it file name desktopPath & theFilename file format format PDF
    end tell
    
end tell
```

The script works absolutely fine if the file is saved to desktopPath & theFilename. However, if I attempt to save to iCloudPath & theFilename, I get the an error:

> Microsoft Word got an error: active document
> doesn’t understand the “save as” message.

I presume that I'm making a really basic mistake here in how I'm constructing the path to the iCloud document folder, but that's the path I get with the following AppleScript snippet:

```
set selected_file to (choose file)
return selected_file as string
```

Any suggestions on what's going wrong here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424036/how-to-use-save-as-command-in-applescript-with-ms-word

Comment: Thanks. Your link gives me a working solution, but I'm not sure why. Can you expand this comment into an answer?

Comment: I can't really. I am not the greatest at Applescript syntax. I was guessing it's maybe the way you're describing paths, but I honestly don't know enough about it to nail it. I'm sure someone will manage to tell you exactly where it was going wrong. Glad the link worked for you though :_

Comment: This is a weird one. Word seems to do things with whatever is fed to `file name`. If you look at the 'events' for your desktopPath save, it actually makes a list containing the alias and the filename as items. Meanwhile, using your iCloudPath on my system, it variously saves it in the user (mine) Documents folder or, if the Word Documents folder is freshly set, there — but never in the 'mobile' folder, which doesn't exist for me. It inconsistently gives the doesn't understand… error. I would speculate that the inconsistency comes from being a property rather than a variable.

Comment: This is indeed a really weird and inconsistent error. I suspect it might be something to do with file permissions, when I have already created a file called "test.pdf", the script works, and I am able overwrite a file that already exists. However if I modify the name to "test2.pdf", the write operation fails again. To clarify, my script works absolutely fine with any other folders except those within the iCloud folder structure

Comment: Try without the 'Letters:' in your path. Doing this with my own path will deposit the test pdf into the icloud drive root folder. Note that I don't think that this is desired behaviour from Apple's perspective. I think that this folder structure is supposed to be synched automatically, i.e. the pdf should be saved in a folder that is managed by the system. Of course, I'm using Sierra and Apple seems to change icloud completely with every OS release. So more likely it's a virtual folder issue than a permissions one.

Comment: Good suggestion, but not working for me. There seems to be something fundamentally broken about the way the iCloud folder is implemented.